# Who is this UID and GID?

Tags: ls

When I do an `ls -l` on my ubuntu machine it shows the number 6226 as the UID and GID for some directories.  Why?  Most files and directories are owned by root, or by ubuntu (which is my usual login name).  It's a AWS machine.

I did a grep on /etc/passwd and /etc/group for 6226 but nothing shows.  I don't think there are any other naming systems in use, such as LDAP.

Comment: How did you bring those files there?  Extracting a tar archive built on other machine as root?

Comment: Yes yaegashi, I think that is exactly how I got the files.

Comment: UIDs don't actually need to be associated with users on the system; they're just numbers which can be associated with files and processes, and which **may** be associated with an actual user in `/etc/passwd`. It's weird, but that's how *nixes work. In other words, it might not be associated with anyone; a ghost in the machine...

Comment: Then you might be able to see that UID/GID in that tar archive.  Try something like `tar --numeric-owner -tzvf archive.tar.gz` to list files in it.

Comment: Which means that if a user on your system happens to have the same numeric UID as the owner of the file on the remote system, that user will end up owning the file. In some contexts that could be a serious problem. If you use the `-o` or `--no-same-owner` option (needed only for `root`), you won't have this problem.